# Have 42 HTML Elements that need to be placed in 3 arrays. Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, split

Kind of a noob question, but I have a page with 42 checkboxes all placed into an array, but I need to split the array into 3 smaller arrays.

```
array(0) = smallOne(0);
array(1) = smallTwo(0);
array(2) = smallThree(0)
array(3) = smallOne(1);
array(4) = smallTwo(1);
array(5) = smallThree(1);
```

And so forth.  Is there a method that does this or will I just need to list them all out?

Here's the javascript so far:

```
function SendForm() {
    var elLength = form1.elements.length;
    var chk = new Array(42);
    var desc = new Array(14);
    var local = new Array(14);
    var other = new Array(14);
    for (i = 0; i < elLength; i++) {
        var count = 0;
        var type = form1.elements[i].type;
        if (type == "checkbox") {
            if (form1.elements[i].checked) {
                chk(count) = true;
            }
            else {
               chk(count) = false;
            }
            count++;
        }
        else {
        }       
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this to assign them:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 14; i++)
{
    var x = i * 3;
    desc[i] = chk[x];
    local[i] = chk[x + 1];
    other[i] = chk[x + 2];
}
```

Comment: I had just come up with that myself and come back here to say so.  Looks like you beat me to the punch :).